# Rstudio : The h5py Python package is required to use pre-built Keras models

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, keras

I’m currently testing Keras for R in Ubuntu environnement. I have made a CPU based quick install of Keras for R in Rstudio with the virtualenv method which is the default one. I am not using Anaconda. (https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/keras/reference/install_keras.html).

```
install.packages("keras")
library(keras)
install_keras()
```

From this point everythink were installed successfully, I decided to follow the Pre-trained Model Resnet50 example (https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/keras/articles/applications.html). I have tried to instantiate the model.

```
library(keras)
library(tensorflow)
library(Rcpp)

# instantiate the model
model <- application_resnet50(weights = 'imagenet')
```

But I have gotten the error message:

```
The h5py Python package is required to use pre-built Keras models
```

I have tried to install h5py with the pip command, import the package h5py as a .tar.gz in my python library folder.
The h5py package is now installed in both the .virtualenv folder and the python library folder, and I still get the same error.

Did I miss something?

Best regards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in R: The h5py Python package is required to save and load models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46819212/error-in-r-the-h5py-python-package-is-required-to-save-and-load-models)